# How to know the size of ParseRelation (Parse/Android)?

Tags: android, parse-platform

Since a ParseRelation can have a huge number of row, is there a performant way to get the number of these rows? 

 
For a big size I cannot simply query all the list and get the size.
In the Parse SDK documentation, it is not recommended to use `query. countInBackground` when there is more than 1000 objects.
So how can I query this size?

**[EDIT]** : potential issue if I increment dedicated counter for the ParseRelation:
Let's say on android I display a list of items with a button to click `"addToRelation"`.
This button should be visible only if the relation is not already done. This means I need first to check on each item if they belong to the relation.
Then, when the user click on several buttons I call for each the backend method to add the relation and increments the counter.  (This already make a lot of Parse request).
Now suppose because of some bad cache synchronization the button "addToRelation" is enabled while the relation already exist for this item.
If I call the method:

```
obj.add("relations",relation);
// increment the relations count by using the increment function
obj.increment("relationsCount");
obj.saveInBackground(. . .)
```

The method will not crash (I tested that if you add twice the same relation nothing happens)
**but the counter will be incremented +1!**

To avoid this I need to check twice on each item if they are not already in relation. This create too much redundant remote requests. 
 So how to avoid this ?

Another issue may a
happen when I use `saveEventually`and the method silently fail; so if the User repeat several times the action, the counter will be incremented/decrimented several times in the local cache for the "`saveEventually`". If for any reason the method save succed finally the counter value will be wrong !!

Answer (score 1):

what you can do is to create additional fields with the name of **realtionCount** (or something else according to your relation name). This field will be integer and then each time you create a new object you can increment this field using the increment option. So your code should look like the following:

```
    // create new relation
    final ParseObject relation = new ParseObject("your_relation_class_name");
    relation.put("{RELATION_KEY_FIELD_NAME}","{RELATION_FIELD_VALUE}");
    // add the relation to the parent object
    obj.add("relations",relation);
    // increment the relations count by using the increment function
    obj.increment("relationsCount");
    obj.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (e == null){
                // object saved!
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I though about this, but for some of my use case the queries become more complex and I might have some data integrity error (I mean the account value may diverge from the list). For example it's difficult to maintain data integrity with a Followers/following use case (like twitter) if some errors occurs during the update process

Comment: That's the reason why you need to update the parent object and not update the relation and then update the parent object. If you use the code above you can make sure that the relation will be created and the count will be updated in one service call.

Comment: I will add an edit to my question to detail my problem with data integrity

Comment: so user can click multiple times on the button? but according to your app logic can he really do that because this is something that you have control on..

Comment: the workflow should be : for each items displayed first check if they are already in relation, if yes display a button "removeFromRelation", if false dispaly a button "addToRelation". but if this first query fail for any unknow issue, I might display the wrong button and for i.e let add an item that is already in relation. To avoid this I need to check a second time (after the click on this button) if the item is already in relation or not. it is not very efficient

Comment: No. you can just check if you didn't receive any error and if not you can be sure that the item is in the relation. Another option is to check if the item has objectId (because you created it)

Comment: I agree, but finally I think the only issue with cache desynchronization can happen with multidevice use case only:
First device add the item in relation (and keep it in cache) so on start the application display the button "removeFromRelation". Then the same user on a second device remove the item from the relation.
On the first device since the item is in relation, I don't query the remote server, if the user click on"removeFromRelation" the counter nbOfItems will be decreased by one since the item was already removed from the other device.

Comment: So the only option is to use count on the server?

Comment: I don't know how to do on the server. For me only 3 options; force to check qith a remote query each time before adding or deleting a Relation (without the local cache), or accept in some really rare case the counter could be wrong (for multi device). third option maybe using a kind of LastmodificationDate somewhere to check if 2 device are synchronized